# What is the locus of points in the plane $\{v : v \cdot (v-a) = 0\}$ for fixed $a$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, orthogonality, locus

Fix $a$ in $\mathbb R^2$.  What is the locus of points $\{v : v \in \mathbb R^2$ and $v \cdot (v-a) = 0\}$?

Clearly, $0$ and $a$ are in this set, and no other multiple of $a$ is in the set.  Beyond that, I'm having trouble characterizing it.

---

### Update

Let $a = (p, q)$.  Then:

$$x^2 + y^2 - px - qy = 0\\
(x - \frac{p}{2})^2 + (y - \frac{q}{2})^2 = r^2$$
where $r = \frac {\sqrt {p^2 + q^2}} 2.$  That is, a circle with center $a/2$ and radius $\|a\|/2$.  Wow.

This obviously implies that $$(v−a/2)⋅(v−a/2)=a/2⋅a/2$$ defines the same circle, which makes sense, because the equation is stating: Take $v$, shift it by $a/2$, and its length squared must equal a constant (namely the length of $a/2$ squared).

I'm still struggling to "see" this in the original equation $v \cdot (v-2b) = 0$.  Does it mean that the locus of points, that when translated by a constant have vectors orthogonal to the midpoint of the translation vector, is a circle? I can't (yet) see that geometrically.

---

## Update

It's Thales' Theorem: If $a/2$ is the center, then $OA$ is a diameter, and $OV \perp AV$ for any $V$ on the circle:
[image]

Or, to put it differently: For any two distinct points $O, A$, a circle is the locus of points $V$ such that $OV \perp AV$.  Then $OA$ is a diameter and $A/2$ the center.

Comment: write $v=(x,y) $ and $a = (a_1, a_2)  $  and calculate. Completing squares is involved

Comment: Maybe it is a cycle  in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @WillJagy No need to use coordinates: $v\cdot(v-a) =0$, then $ (v-a/2)\cdot(v-a/2) = a/2\cdot a/2$.

Comment: @jjagmath  sure. I was hoping that supplying a framework that would seem more familiar would induce the OP to give it a try, I guess that did not happen. I also liked the bit about inscribed triangles with one edge a diameter

Comment: Robert, how about if you type the equation (with $x,y,a_1, a_2$ )  at the end of your equation  to begin with

Comment: @WillJagy Got it! Thanks! Please take a look.  Also: What type of course or text covers these multivariate algebra cases? It seems to be a gap in my skills, but I can't find a good reference, source, or method.

Comment: fine.  Note that you were able to fill in the steps above, after which you were able to write things as vectors; keep practicing one-variable algebra, don't be too quick to tell us you can't use our hints.   On this problem:  there is a triangle with vertices $0, a, v.$   How does it fit in the circle, and what kind of triangle is it?  For example, take $a = (6,8)$  Where is the circle center? Can you find some other points on the circle with integer coordinates $v=(x,y)?$  Helps to draw an actual picture. There is a geometry theorem  illustrated here...

Comment: @WillJagy Thales Theorem! Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You have answered your own question.

$0$ as a null vector does not occur here. It occurs as a scalar dot product.

The dot product is the statement of Thales thm in vector form. Vectors  $(v,v-a)$ are orthogonal and the locus is a semi-circle containing all right angled triangle vertices. Only a single case is drawn.

[image]