# Help finding the intersection of a cone and its tangent plane using vector methods

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Find the intersection of a cone and its tangent plane.

My partial solution is below.  Please help me complete it.

*Note: Solutions exist. This question asks to help me complete **my** solution, which uses vector methods.*

---

For any point $v$ in the plane, let $c(v) : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be the non-negative $z$-coordinate on the cone for $v$.  Then $$c(v) = \|v\|$$ and $$Dc(v) = \frac {v^\top} {\|v\|}.$$

Fix $a$ in the plane, and let $T_a$ be the plane tangent to the cone at $(a, \|a\|)$. For any point $v$ in the plane, let $t_a(v): \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be the $z$-coordinate over $v$ of $T_a$.  Then $$\begin{align*}
t_a(v) &= c(v) + Dc(a)(v-a) \\
&= \|v\| + \frac{v^\top (v-a)}{\|v\|} \\
&= \|v\| + \frac {v} {\|v\|} \cdot (v-a).
\end{align*}$$

For $z \geq 0$, the cone and $T_a$ intersect at $(v, z)$ iff $z = t_a(v) = c(v)$, which is when $v \cdot (v-a) = 0$ and $z = \|v\|$.  If $a = 0$, this is the point at the origin.

Otherwise (for $a \neq 0$), I believe this will be a ray through the origin, and by symmetry the intersection below (for $z < 0$) will extend the ray to a line through the origin - but am having trouble completing the proof.  (See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4721382/what-is-the-locus-of-points-in-the-plane-v-v-cdot-v-a-0-for-fixed)).

---

## Update

What I wrote above is incorrect.  *Thank you to Ted Shifrin for helping me find this mistake!*  Rather, it should be

$$\begin{align*}
t_a(v) &= c(a) + Dc(a)(v-a) \quad \text{(Here was my error!)}\\
&= \|a\| + \frac{v^\top (v-a)}{\|v\|} \\
&= \|a\| + \frac {v} {\|v\|} \cdot (v-a) \\
\end{align*}$$

So the projection of the intersection onto the $xy$ plane is the locus of points $v$ such that $\|v\| = \|a\| + \frac {v} {\|v\|} \cdot (v-a)$, and the intersection is the set $\{(v, \|v\|)\}$.  I'm still struggling to prove this is a line through the origin.

Comment: Why should $z=c(v)$?

Comment: But conversely? $t_a(v)= c(v)$ for any differentiable function $c$, no?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I believe I understand your point.  $z = -c(v)$ is also a solution when $z < 0$.  I restricted $c$ to give the nonnegative $z$ value, but made no restriction for the tangent plane (and indeed can't make any such restriction, because it's not symmetric around $xy$ plane!).  Where does this leave things? Does this somehow invalidate my entire approach, or can I fix it?

Comment: I think you want $(v,t_a(v))=(w,c(w))$?

Comment: @TedShifrin > "$t_a(v)=c(v)$  for any differentiable function $c$, no?" Certainly.  But only for cones will $Dc(v) = v/\|v\|$.